# Join "third party" table using JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: spring, jpa, groovy

I´m at my whits end and would love some input to keep me going.

I am trying to use Spring JPA with CriteriaBuilder to query for apartments whose $coordinate  is at a smaller distance than X from $distance.firstCoordinate

Basically I want to recreate this SQL query:

`select * from apartment a left join distance d on d.SECOND_COORDINATE=a.COORDINATE where d.DISTANCE <=909`

The distance object below has two Coordinate objects (firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate).

- firstCoordinate is a reference point shared by most Distances
- secondCoordinate are the same coordinates used by apartment objects.

These are my entities:

```
@Entity
class Apartment implements Persistable\<Long\> {

    @JoinColumn(name = "coordinate")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Coordinate coordinate
    
    .....

}

@Entity
class Coordinate implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id
    
    double latitude
    double longitude
    .....

}

@Entity
class Distance implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "distanceidgenerator", initialValue = 1000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "distanceidgenerator")
    long id
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "firstCoordinate")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [ CascadeType.MERGE], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Coordinate firstCoordinate
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "secondCoordinate")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [ CascadeType.MERGE], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Coordinate secondCoordinate
    
    double distance
    ......

}
```

I´ve tried several combos of joining apartment, coordinate and distance together, also several Criteria roots but I can't seem to get it right.

I have several other predicates/filtering that I want to combine as well, they are all simple and work well but they keep we from wanting to just write a String query.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't know whether the relationship before your `Apartment` and `Distance` is `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany`.Now, I assume that the relationship between them is `OneToMany`.You can add a non-foreign key association of `Distance` to the `Apartment` entity.

```java
@Data
@Entity
@FieldNameConstants
public class Apartment {

    @Id
    String id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "coordinate")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Coordinate coordinate;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(
            referencedColumnName = "coordinate",
            name = "second_coordinate",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)
    )
    List<Distance> distance;
}
```

The other entities:

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Coordinate {

    @Id
    long id;

    double latitude;

    double longitude;

}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
@FieldNameConstants
public class Distance {

    @Id
    String id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "first_coordinate")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Coordinate firstCoordinate;

    @JoinColumn(name = "second_coordinate")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Coordinate secondCoordinate;

    double distance;
}
```

JpaSpecificationExecutor:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class SpecTest {

    @Autowired
    ApartmentRepository apartmentRepository;

    @Test
    void test() {
        List<Apartment> all = apartmentRepository.findAll((root, query, cb) -> {
            Join<Apartment, Distance> join = root.join(Apartment.Fields.distance, JoinType.LEFT);
            return cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(join.get(Distance.Fields.distance), 999);
        });
    }
}
```

The final output of the sql on the console:

```sql
select a1_0.id,a1_0.coordinate from apartment a1_0 left join distance d1_0 on a1_0.coordinate=d1_0.second_coordinate where d1_0.distance<=?
```

Above is the java code, hope it can help you.